# Headless Wordpress API call from Astro react component to fetch posts and display featured post image problem: some featured images not showing

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest, headless

Hello please help me debug this issue if you can:

I am building a headless wordpress website using Astro.js
I setup a component to fetch posts from wordpress which I am able to do, but I want if post has featured image to show image, if no featured image to show a placeholder image

the problem is some images are showing and some posts that have featured images set still do not show, below is my component code, for full github repo is here: https://github.com/mhafez1978/pwwl-astro-project.

````
```
````

Start

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const PostList = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const postsPerPage = 9;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://prestigeworldwidelimos.com/carolina-limo-rentals/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&page=${currentPage}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setPosts(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching events:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchAllPosts();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const indexOfLastEvent = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstEvent = indexOfLastEvent - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstEvent, indexOfLastEvent);

  // Helper function to handle pagination navigation
  const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {currentPosts.map((post) => (
            <a
              key={post.id}
              className="col-lg-4 mb-4"
              href={post.link}
              target="_blank"
            >
              <div
                className="card d-flex flex-column"
                style={{
                  width: "20rem",
                  height: "400px",
                  borderRadius: "4px",
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "column",
                }}
              >
                {post._embedded &&
                post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"] &&
                post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0] &&
                post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url ? (
                  <>
                    <img
                      className="card-img-top"
                      style={{ objectFit: "cover", height: "200px" }}
                      src={post._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url}
                      alt={post.title.rendered}
                    />
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <img
                    className="card-img-top"
                    style={{
                      objectFit: "cover",
                      height: "200px",
                      //   position: "relative",
                    }}
                    src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg"
                    alt={post.title.rendered}
                  />
                )}
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h3 style={{ fontSize: "18px", paddingRight: "20px" }}>
                    {post.title.rendered.substring(0, 32)}
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "45px" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ul className="pagination">
              <li
                className={`page-item ${currentPage === 1 ? "disabled" : ""}`}
              >
                <button
                  className="page-link"
                  onClick={() => handlePageChange(currentPage - 1)}
                >
                  Previous
                </button>
              </li>
              {Array.from({
                length: Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage),
              }).map((_, index) => (
                <li
                  className={`page-item ${
                    currentPage === index + 1 ? "active" : ""
                  }`}
                  key={index + 1}
                >
                  <button
                    className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => handlePageChange(index + 1)}
                  >
                    {index + 1}
                  </button>
                </li>
              ))}
              <li
                className={`page-item ${
                  currentPage === Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage)
                    ? "disabled"
                    : ""
                }`}
              >
                <button
                  className="page-link"
                  onClick={() => handlePageChange(currentPage + 1)}
                >
                  Next
                </button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PostList;
```

End

Comment: I am also seeing CORS issues even though I set it to allow '*' on wordpress using a plugin